# Native calendar event handling

Tags: database, blackberry, calendar

Can I open my custom developed form [instead of native one] when user opens any pre-created appointment/event from calendar view ?

Can this be achieved ? if yes, how ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no way to get that particular type of notification from the calendar.  You can use a `PIMListListener` to be notified of when an appointment/event is added, removed, or updated, but not when it is opened.  Once it is in the calendar, then calendar handles the UI for it.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. By any chance is the OS 7 offering any such feature ?